# php + Ajax + Json page submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a business functionality to do Employee search (Ajax), on submitting the form. I have to load employee details by using JQuery based Ajax.
Following is my search code. The issue is after submitting the form, `<div id="emp"></div>` is not populated with values. in `Employee.php` page I see json object, was able to print employees.

I guess below form is submitting, but not returning to page after json object is created. Could someone help me how can I make this as ajax based call.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        //alert('test');
        $(".js-ajax-php-json").submit(function(){
            alert('test');
            $.getJSON("Employee.php", function (jsoncontent)
            {
                alert(jsoncontent);
                jsonArray = jsoncontent;

                for(var i =0;i < jsonArray.length-1;i++)
{
  var emp = jsonArray[i];
   $("#emp").html(i+" "+emp[0].lastname + " - " + emp[0].firstname+ " - " ); 
}
   });
   });
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form class="js-ajax-php-json" action="Employee.php" method="GET">
         <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" style='width:300px' name="srch-term" id="srch-term" placeholder="Enter the Employee Name">
            <span class="input-group-btn"><input type="submit"  value="search" class="btn btn-success"></input></span>
          </div>
        </form>
<div id="emp"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        //alert('test');
        $(".js-ajax-php-json").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); //prevent the form from submitting.

            $.getJSON("Employee.php", function (jsoncontent)
            {
                alert(jsoncontent);
                jsonArray = jsoncontent;

                for(var i =0;i < jsonArray.length-1;i++)
{
  var emp = jsonArray[i];
   $("#emp").html(i+" "+emp[0].lastname + " - " + emp[0].firstname+ " - " ); 
}
   });
   });
   });
</script>
```

you have missed the `preventDefault()` to prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  
I tried using preventDefault(), the page is not getting submitted,in that case my employee.php will not be called and JSon object will not be created.
As per my requirement the Search results should get be displayed within the same page(search.php) without redirecting to other page (employee.php).

For instance, In walmart.com , when we search for the product the search result will be displayed on the same page without redirecting/reloading to other page.